# Re-Delegation Smart Contract

Tags: smart-contract, stake-pool, staking, contracts

**Prelude:** I have a micro-cardano-pool ,less than 10K include 3 deligators (my friends). Despite the sike of the pool, I would like my pool be an active element in the mainnet network. Therefore I decided to participate in the  interesting small-pools cooperative where all participants delegates their stake to a certain pool (from the programm) for several epochs. The number of epochs that allocated to the current active pool is a function of the stake contributed by that pool to the program in the recent past.

**Current state :** My friends and me delegate our stakes eccording to the program schedule (each one his stake).

**Proposal :** My proposal is to create a smart contract where few delegators  will move their stake to this contract and only one (contract manager) could delegate the whole stake of the smart contract to a certain pool. Every participant (include contract manager) can pull  only his part from the contract .

**Question :** Is it possible to delegate a smart contract’s stake ?
What are the alternatives to the above smart contract?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If staking rights are being managed by a single trusted entity, then smart contracts are not necessary for your schema. Rather, you can use "franken-addresses", which are **addresses built using multiple payment keys, but a single staking key.**

In short, you and your peers may generate your own payment key pairs using `cardano-cli`, `cardano-wallet`, or whatever derivation path(s) you prefer. Your "staking manager" then generates their staking key-pair using similar methods. Finally, addresses are built with `cardano-cli address build` for each participant using their payment.vkey and the manager's stake.vkey.

Now, every participant gets their own wallet that they can deposit/withdraw from themselves, while all the wallets' staking rights are controlled by a single keyholder.

---

Note: if implemented, the cohort must agree on a scheme as to who will be paying fees. As it stands, each wallet will require it's own staking certificate, which costs 2 ADA, plus standard tx-fee costs for delegation/redelegation.

Pro tip: you can save on some tx-fees if you submit the staking certificates all in single transaction.

Comment: On a slightly tangential note, check out the [Conclave Paper](https://iohk.io/en/research/library/papers/conclavea-collective-stake-pool-protocol/) by IOHK - really cool idea for collective pool management.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a smart contract (script address) can delegate.

An example plutus script address from week 2 in the pioneers course is shown below:

```
Address {addressCredential = ScriptCredential 67f33146617a5e61936081db3b2117cbf59bd2123748f58ac9678656, addressStakingCredential = Nothing}
```

Note the parameter `addressStakingCredential` which allows a script address to be staked against a pool.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article - it's pretty well written and explains the inner workings of how delegation works using Plutus!

[Liqwid Labs Stake Validators](https://github.com/Plutonomicon/plutonomicon/blob/main/stake-scripts.md)